# Python Beautiful Soup stops parsing

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I try to parse the attached text.txt file (with html syntax) by the following script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pattern = re.compile("www.geocaching.com")
f=open("text.txt")
text=f.read()
f.close()
s = BeautifulSoup(text)
a = s.find_all(href=pattern)
print(len(a))
print (a[len(a)-1])
```

My expectation is to have all tags with href="www.geocaching.com", but I do not get all from the file attached.
The last one is:

```
<a class="lnk " href="http://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC3HWHJ_corse-known-unknown-2-view-on-ile-de-giraglia"><span>Corse known &amp; unknown 2 - View on Ile de Giraglia</span></a>
```

if I delete the lines 626-674, containing only some simple html code, I get the next two, i.e. the last is

```
<a class="lnk " href="http://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC3MEDG_tour-genoise-dagnello"><span>TOUR GENOISE D'AGNELLO</span></a>
```

but again I don't get all results I can find manually in the html file.

The file I use is from here (I downloaded it to use it locally)
https://www.geocaching.com/seek/nearest.aspx?lat=43.410333&lon=09.0476&dist=100

Comment: I tried your code using BS3 and its giving me the last link as well

Comment: If I open link with urllib2 it gives me length of a = 42.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS Selector instead in the following way :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("text.txt")
text = f.read()
f.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

# this find all the href containing the text "www.geocaching.com"
links =  soup.select('[href]~="www.geocaching.com"')
```